# Trying to update the state of the counter in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management

havent been working with React in quite a while. Just got back into it and was trying to update the state. From my knowledge, I should be able to update the state using the method below. However, its not updating the value of the age. Am I missing something?

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      age: 0
    }

    this.increaseAge = this.increaseAge.bind(this)
  }

  increaseAge=()=> {
    this.setState({
      age: this.state.age + 1
    })

    console.log("hi")
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div className="app-content">
        <h1>Hey Ninjas</h1>
        <p>{this.state.age}</p>
        <button onClick={this.icreaseAge}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: BTW, I am aware that I do not need to bind the function since I am using the arrow function. But was just trying out all possiblilities

Comment: Is the console logging "hi"?  I see that in your onClick it's `this.icreaseAge` instead of `this.increaseAge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onClick={this.icreaseAge}>Increment</button>
```

You got a typo in the onClick. otherwise it should be working just fine.

```
<button onClick={this.increaseAge}>Increment</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the typo!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, You missed the letter (n) from `increaseAge`

This should work now.

```
        <button onClick={this.increaseAge}>Increment</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote, you shouldn't update your `state` by accessing the component's `state` the way you did, but rather this way:

```
increaseAge = () => {
  this.setState((state) => ({ age: state.age + 1 }));
  // or shorter
  this.setState(({ age }) => ({ age: age + 1 }));
}
```

The problem with your implementation arises from a fact that React's state updates are asynchronous and can be batched so your `age` update could finally end up with `age` being overwritten by some other `setState` call and then eventually being updated incorrectly.

You may take a look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).